# Overriding <head> tag within Django template

Tags: django

I have a Django application where users upload videos (played back via html5 `video` tag). To handle edge cases where a user is unable to playback the video, I give them the option to download it.

For this, I'm writing JS that ensures a "download" button appears whenever a `src` isn't loading. Here take a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/o8YFZNaEhpJMg4YPhZCO?p=preview

The problem is that my JS resides within `<head></head>` and it needs to be able to access all videos I'm going to show on page.

Normally, I pass video objects as an `object_list` that I then iterate through (generated through a paginated `ListView`). But all this happens in the `body` of template.

How can I get access to `context[object_list]` within `<head`> so that the JS snippet I've shared can utilize the sources (I'm already inheriting `<head>` from base.html)? Secondly, how do I ensure I only pass *video sources in page* to my JS snippet?

Can someone give me an illustrative example via which I can solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a `block` in your `base.html` that you can override in your object list template.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a

```
{% block video_head_tag %}  
{% endblock %}
```

inside your `<head></head>` tag in the parent template "base.html"

on your child template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block video_head_tag %}you_object_list{% endblock %}
```

Reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance